# ListBlobsSegmented - based on suffix/extension

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I like the **ListBlobsSegmented** method that allows me to go through blobs in defined count chunks. However is it possible to get only those blobs that end up with **".xml"** for example?

```
var blobList = cloudBlobContainer.ListBlobsSegmented(string.Empty,
                    false,
                    BlobListingDetails.None,
                    blobLimit,
                    continuationToken,
                    new BlobRequestOptions
                    {
                        LocationMode = LocationMode.PrimaryOnly
                    },
                    null);
```

this is the method I am using now after which I filter the out the xml blobs like this:

```
var xmlBlobs = blobList.Results.Where(b => Path.GetExtension(b.Uri.AbsolutePath).Equals(".xml", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

However this does not seem very effective to me. I wonder if there is a better way/more effective to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using the most effective way, since ListBlobs API doesn't support filtering with suffix on the server side.